# Node Server only receiving first "get"

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I have a client app written in Javascript that communicates with a Node server like this:

```
// event listener for the listen button click
    document.getElementById("Start").addEventListener("click", function(){
        // only do stuff if we haven't already started
        if(!started){
            // instantiate HTTP request to send to the server
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var getString = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?type=start&port="+PORT;
            console.log(getString);
            // send it away
            xmlhttp.open("GET", getString, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

            // start some other process on the client side
            startProcess();
            // set the listening flag
            started = true;
        }
    });

    // event listener for the stop button click
    document.getElementById("Stop").addEventListener("click", function(){
        // only do stuff if we're currently listening
        if(started){
            // we're stopped now
            started = false;

            // stop the client process
            stopProcess();

            // send another request to the server to stop whatever's going on there
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var getString = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/?type=stop";
            xmlhttp.open("GET", getString, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    });
```

On the server, I'm using Express and simply have

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // do some stuff to handle the request
    var type = req.query.type;
    if(type == 'start'){
        var port = req.query.port;
        // do some stuff
    }else if(type == 'stop'){
        // do some other stuff
    }
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){});
```

But I've tried this using Node's HTTP as well and gotten the exact same results, so this problem is likely not related to Express. The issue is when I start up the server and open an instance of the client app and click "Start," everything works properly. Then when I click "Stop," everything works properly again. However, if I try to click "Start" again in the same instance of the client app, nothing happens. It appears from the client side that the HTTP request is getting sent- however, the server never receives it, as the app.get callback is never called. I'm pretty inexperienced with HTTP stuff so I have a vague suspicion I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, but I've been unable to figure it out so far.

Comment: The value of `getString` is likely to be important, please post it.

Comment: Sorry, the omitted bracket was a copy/paste error. It's there in the actual code, I promise, haha. And I added some detail with respect to `getString`.

Comment: It's always a red flag when you see a full path in an ajax request. But provided your path to the page where this is running is *also* within the origin `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, it should work (and does, in my local testing). The problem lies in something other than the quoted code. If the page this code is on is **not** in the origin `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, then that's your problem, and I can't see why it would work even once, thanks to the Same Origin Protocol.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean the client stuff...

Comment: @user2871915 is it possible something is interfering with your code by changing the value of `started`? can't tell with your code because we can't see whether it was defined globally or within a scope.

Comment: @Tobi: What I see on the client is boring old normal everyday XHR.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility

Comment: @Tobi the point is websockets is irrelevant to this question. Switching to websockets is unlikely to even solve this problem because the xhr is unlikely to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Tobi: What's the point is posting a random link to MDN? If you're trying to FUD about something being unsupported, none of what the OP is doing is unsupported in any browser released since 2005. Enough now, this is not constructive.

Comment: Well, I know all of that. I just wanted to give a hint to the socket.io library which (to me) seems to provide a lot/all functionality the OP wants to build. And, it's well-tested and will work with a lot of browser versions. XHR is not supported everywhere in the same way. That's all. No point to argue.

Comment: Is your app.get properly returning content to the client in the stop condition? i'd suggest simplifying it to `res.send(req.query.type); return;` to rule out any express issues.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't returning properly. Thanks. I'll accept that as an answer.

Comment: @user2871915: Sounds like it was something outside of the question. That being the case, the best thing is just to delete the question as it won't be useful to others later. Glad you figured it out. :-)